# Ramanujan 1918 paper

Tags: reference-request, arithmetic-functions, ramanujan-summation

Does anybody know where I can find Ramanujan's paper from 1918 titled "On Certain Arithmetical Functions." It is referenced in wikipedia, under the Ramanujan Summation section, but I cannot find a link to it. It is supposed to contain proofs to some interesting identities.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ramanujan's Collected Papers are available at http://www.imsc.res.in/~rao/ramanujan/collectedindex.html.

The paper you seek is available at http://www.imsc.res.in/~rao/ramanujan/CamUnivCpapers/Cpaper18/page1.htm but it's from 1916 not 1918.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, thanks, I hadn't noticed the frames when I copied the URL. I've fixed the link in the answer.

Comment: Yeah, frames are so 1999. :)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest [Ramanujan's collected works.](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s24/sh/278e21c8-56cc-40ea-8974-772bac39c8e8/e2083b0cd1fee73d90560a82f578ec8c)