On Dougall's results of Hypergeometric functions
I want to prove that $${}_5F_4\left(\begin{array}{cc}n/2+1, n ,-x,-y,-z \\
n/2 ,x+n+1,y+n+1,z+n+1\end{array};1\right)=\frac{\Gamma(x+n+1)\Gamma(y+n+1)\Gamma(z+n+1)\Gamma(x+y+z+n+1)}{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(x+y+n+1)\Gamma(y+z+n+1)\Gamma(x+z+n+1)} \tag{1}$$

Approach: By Gauss Hypergeometric theorem, I realized that the right-hand side is equal to the fractions $$\frac{{}_2F_1(y,z;x+y+z+n+1;1)}{{}_2F_1(y,z;y+z+n+1;1)}\quad \quad \text{or} \quad \quad \frac{{}_2F_1(-x,-y;z+n+1;1)}{{}_2F_1(-x,-y;n+1;1)}$$
(I can swap $x,y,z$ and the fraction still remains true). This suggests that I should multiply both sides by the denominator and consider that product of hypergeometric functions.
Also, the products are a cyclic product of even number of elements at the denominator and odd number of elements on the numerator (This also appears in a more general form).
A corollary of $(1)$ is Dixon theorem. That could be proved by using Gauss Hypergeometric theorem. So I am very tempted to utilize it here.

Dougall's original proof for the more general version is available at https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/proceedings-of-the-edinburgh-mathematical-society/article/on-vandermondes-theorem-and-some-more-general-expansions/08C00E935E5D3139F9FEDED470EBDB20

@ParamanandSingh Amazing! The derivation utilizing symmetry is so clever. I just finished reading the proof, I'll type the answer in later.

Great, it is always nice to have the proofs of well known results available on math se. Waiting eagerly for your answer.

A nice application of Dougall formula is available at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3686262/72031

As @ParamanandSingh commented, Dougall's original paper is linked here. Since the paper is written in an old style, it is quite hard to read. This answer is a modification of Dougall's original proof. Considering that currently there are no proofs typed on the internet, I will present the proof as detailed as possible so various level of math learners could understand.

I will denote the rising and falling factorials as
$$a^{\overline n}=a(a+1)\cdots(a+n-1) \quad ,\quad a^{\underline n}=a(a-1)\cdots(a-n+1)$$
Start by considering the function
$$f(x,s)=\frac{(x+a+1)^{\overline s}(x+b+1)^{\overline s}(c+1)^{\overline s}(d+1)^{\overline s}}{(a+1)^{\overline s}(b+1)^{\overline s}(x+c+1)^{\overline s}(x+d+1)^{\overline s}}$$
where $s$ is a positive integer and constrain the expression to $a+b=c+d$. We can see the following properties of $f$

$f$ is symmetric ($f(x,s)=f(s,x)$)
$f(x,s)$ is invariant under $x\mapsto -x-c-d-s-1$

Dougall then expand the function $f$ as an infinite sum, in a way such that the expansion posses the above two properties.
$$f(x,s)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}A_k \frac{x^{\underline k}s^{\underline k} (x+c+d+s+1)^{\overline k}}{(x+c+1)^{\overline k}(s+c+1)^{\overline k}(x+d+s)^{\underline k}}$$
where $A_k$ are coefficients independent of $s$ and $x$ yet determined. To find $A_k$, we multiply both sides by $(x+d+1)^{\overline s}$ and take the limit as $x\to -d-1$
$$\begin{split}\lim_{x\to -d-1}\{(x+d+1)^{\overline s}f(x,s)\}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}A_k \lim_{x\to -d-1}\left\{\frac{x^{\underline k}s^{\underline k} (x+c+d+s+1)^{\overline k}(x+d+1)^{\overline s}}{(x+c+1)^{\overline k}(s+c+1)^{\overline k}(x+d+s)^{\underline k}}\right\}
\end{split}$$
We note that since there is a $s^{\underline k}$ in the summand, the sum is null for $k>s$. now take a look at the expression
$$\frac{(x+d+1)^{\overline s}}{(x+d+s)^{\underline k}}=\begin{cases}1,\quad s=k \\ (x+d+s-k)\cdots(x+d+1), \quad k<s\end{cases}$$
and notice that if we take the limit $x\to -d-1$ the expression is non zero only if $k=s$, so the limit reduces to
$$\lim_{x\to -d-1}\{(x+d+1)^{\overline s}f(x,s)\}=A_s\lim_{x\to -d-1}\frac{x^{\underline s} s!(x+c+d+s+1)^{\overline s}}{(x+c+1)^{\overline s}(s+c+1)^{\overline s}}$$
$$=A_s\frac{(-d-1)^{\underline s}s!(s+c)^{\overline s}}{(c-d)^{\overline s}(s+c+1)^{\overline s}}=A_s\frac{(-1)^s(d+1)^{\overline s}s!(s+c)}{(c-d)^{\overline s}(2s+c)}$$
Where using the definition of $f$, the left hand side is equal to $$\lim_{x\to -d-1}\{(x+d+1)^{\overline s}f(x,s)\}=\frac{(c+1)^{\overline s}(d+1)^{\overline s}}{(a+1)^{\overline s}(b+1)^{\overline s}}\frac{(a-d)^{\overline s}(b-d)^{\overline s}}{(c-d)^{\overline s}}$$
Putting together we get
$$A_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\cdot\frac{2n+c}{n+c}\cdot \frac{(a-d)^{\overline n}(b-d)^{\overline n}(c+1)^{\overline n}}{(a+1)^{\overline n}(b+1)^{\overline n}}$$
To see symmetry, we write $a$ as $y+c$, $b$ as $z+c$ and $d$ as $z+y+c$ to change the expression into the form
$$\frac{(x+y+c+1)^{\overline s}(z+y+c+1)^{\overline s}(x+z+c+1)^{\overline s}(c+1)^{\overline s}}{(x+c+1)^{\overline s}(y+c+1)^{\overline s}(z+c+1)^{\overline s}(x+y+z+c+1)^{\overline s}}$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\frac{2k+c}{k+c}\frac{(-z)^{\overline k}(-y)^{\overline k}(c+1)^{\overline k}}{(y+c+1)^{\overline k}(z+c+1)^{\overline k}}\cdot \frac{x^{\underline k}s^{\underline k}(x+y+z+s+2c+1)^{\overline k}}{(x+c+1)^{\overline k}(s+c+1)^{\overline k}(x+y+z+c+1)^{\underline k}}$$
Finally, we take $s$ to infinity. Note that $\lim_{s\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(s+a)}{\Gamma(s)a^s}=1$. The left hand side is equal to
$$\frac{\Gamma(x+c+1)\Gamma(y+c+1)\Gamma(z+c+1)\Gamma(x+y+z+c+1)}{\Gamma(c+1)\Gamma(x+y+c+1)\Gamma(x+z+c+1)\Gamma(y+z+c+1)}$$
The right hand side is equal to
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\frac{2k+c}{k+c}\frac{(-z)^{\overline k}(-y)^{\overline k}(c+1)^{\overline k}x^{\underline k}}{(y+c+1)^{\overline k}(z+c+1)^{\overline k}(x+c+1)^{\overline k}}\cdot {\underbrace{\lim_{s\to\infty}\frac{s^{\underline k}(x+y+z+s+2c+1)^{\overline k}}{(s+c+1)^{\overline k}(x+y+z+c+1)^{\underline k}}}_{=1}}$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2k+c}{c}\cdot \frac{(-x)^{\overline k}(-y)^{\overline k}(-z)^{\overline k}c^{\overline k}}{(x+c+1)^{\overline k}(y+c+1)^{\overline k}(z+c+1)^{\overline k}k!}$$
$$={}_5F_4\left(\begin{array}{cc}c/2+1, c ,-x,-y,-z \\
c/2 ,x+n+1,y+n+1,z+n+1\end{array};1\right)$$
This completes the proof.
As you can see, the proof utilizes no advanced theory of Hypergeometric series.  All of it were elementary algebraic manipulations and a clever expansion.
Also, note that the condition writing as an infinite sum is $\Re(x+y+z+c)>-1$.

PS. If we take $z\to\infty$, we get
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2n+c}{c}\frac{(-x)^{\overline n}(-y)^{\overline n}c^{\overline n}}{(x+c+1)^{\overline n}(y+c+1)^{\overline n}n!}(-1)^n =\frac{\Gamma(x+c+1)\Gamma(y+c+1)}{\Gamma(c+1)\Gamma(x+y+c+1)}$$
For example, set $c=1/2$, $x=y=-1/2$ gives
$$\frac{2}{\pi}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(4n+1)}{4^{3n}}\binom{2n}{n}^3(-1)^n$$
